# Super Mario Maker: Course Comments

Tags: super-mario-maker

I see all these questions on how to turn them off so they don't see them. But, I want to know how to disable people from making comments on my stage when they are in the level, but can still comment after it. You can see this being used in Goomba Story by Hype.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to delete comments within the level one by one by going to Course World, pressing the "-" button (select) or by tapping your Mii in the top-left corner, going to the level, clicking on "Comments" (the green tab) and deleting each comment that appears with a picture of the middle of the level.